# Filter by specific store but not exclusively

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the table 'products' which contains products, including the column [name], which has the product name. This table is connected to the table 'receipt_items', which contains items found in receipts. The connection is done through the columns 'products'[id] - 'receipt_items'[product_id]. The 'receipt_items' table is also connected to the table 'domains', which contains stores. The connection is done through the columns 'receipt_items'[domain_id] - 'domains'[id]. The 'receipt_items' table also has the column [purchase_price] which has the price of an item.

I want to display in a table all the product names, for every store they are sold, and their price there. However, I only want to show products that are sold from a specific store (meaning a specific 'domain'[id]), along with the other stores that sell these specific products. My issue is that if I just filter for 'domain'[id], the table only shows the specific store and the price, and not the other stores that also sell this product. How would I be able to manage this?

TL;DR: I want to filter for products sold by a specific store, but show all the stores that sell this specific product.

Comment: Rough outline: you may want to create a helper table to select the product from (this table is not connected to any other table.) It serves to filter for the stores selling this product via a measure.